# 18.04 - O2+ODAC sound only plays during mouse movement

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I wanted go get more familiar with Linux, therefore I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot).
There is a O2+ODAC USB soundcard installed which works on windows. Therefore, a hardware fault can be ruled out. However, on Ubuntu it is only possible to play sounds during mouse movement. I already tried to play with the pulseaudio config `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0`. I also tried using a different USB2 port. The issue applies to all tested sources of sound (firefox,vlc).
The onboard analog output works however.

Does anyone know what I could try / what to search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not detect the issue, but I found a workaround. While gathering information with `lsdev`, I saw my system has two USB controllers. After switching the DAC to the second controller, the sound immediately played like it should.

I think it could be an issue related to IRQ conflict (if someone needs a point to start when having a similar issue). However, I won't investigate this any further as the workaround is sufficient for me.